# Adding Leaflet layer control to sidebar

Tags: javascript, leaflet, sidebar

I'm using the [Leaflet sidebar V2](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2) plugin and am wondering if it is possible to put a leaflet layer control menu into the sidebar? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yes it's possible ofc, but you would need to create your own leaflet layer control and to do the layer switching from there, there isn't any integration with the plugin just to move it in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186131/placing-controls-outside-map-container-with-leaflet) hint. It removes the L.control element from the map container and adds it to a new parent. You can do this for the sidebar straight forward.

HTML:

```
 <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar collapsed">
   <div class="sidebar-tabs">
    <ul role="tablist">
     <li>....</li>
     <li>....</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar-content">
   <div class="sidebar-pane" id="">  
    <h1 class="sidebar-header">...</h1>
    <div id="example"> <!--Here the layer control menu will be added--></div>    
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var layer = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);

  var htmlObject = layer.getContainer();
  var a = document.getElementById('example')
  function setParent(el, newParent){
    newParent.appendChild(el);
  }
  setParent(htmlObject, a);
```

For me, this solution worked well.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution with getContainer(); works well:

```
var control = L.Routing.control(L.extend(
        {},
        {
            waypoints: [],
            ...
        }))
        .addTo(map);

var oldLayerControl = control.getContainer();
var newLayerControl = jQuery("#siedebarRoutingContainer");
newLayerControl.append(oldLayerControl);
```

and CSS:

```
.leaflet-routing-geocoder-result{  /* leaflet routing machine -> src -> autocomplete.js Zeile 20 */
   z-index:99999999999 !important;
}
```

Inspired by https://codepen.io/ItsMeStevieG/pen/QRgWNR