# Leaflet sidebar-v2

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, sidebar

[Adding Leaflet layer control to sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41475855/7711916) holds my question that was not answered in a way I can understand.

**Marko replies with:**
Yes it's possible ofc, but you would need to create your own leaflet layer control and to do the layer switching from there, there isn't any integration with the plugin just to move it in the sidebar. – Marko Letic Jan 5 at 14:46

How do I add layer switching after I have my layer control?