# How to use "createButtonCallback" from leaflet-locatecontrol

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, sidebar

I want to replace the default locate button from the leaflet-locatecontrol
plugin by another one in a div element inside a sidebar (leaflet sidebar v2).

Here is an example :
https://vprint.github.io/#14/13.4413/103.8591

What I want to do is to call the locate function when I click on the left location button (the one on the left sidebar) which is created with this line

```
<li class="disabled">

    <a href="#locate" role="tab" onclick="LocateMe()">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </a>

</li>
```

I saw the "CreateButtonCallback" option on locate plugin documentation, but how can I use it to resolve my problem?

The only documentation I found about it is this one, but i don't understand it :

```
/**
* This callback can be used in case you would like to override button creation behavior.
* This is useful for DOM manipulation frameworks such as angular etc.
* This function should return an object with HtmlElement for the button (link property) and the icon (icon property).
*/
createButtonCallback: function (container, options) {
   var link = L.DomUtil.create('a', 'leaflet-bar-part leaflet-bar-part-single', container);
   link.title = options.strings.title;
   var icon = L.DomUtil.create(options.iconElementTag, options.icon, link);
   return { link: link, icon: icon };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question :

I finally found out a solution following this trick : [Adding Leaflet layer control to sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41475855/adding-leaflet-layer-control-to-sidebar)

If you want to add location control in the sidebar (or any other plugin) you have to create a div element inside the li class as following :

HTML

```
<li class="disabled">
  <a href="#LocateMe" role="tab">
    <div id="#LocateMe"></div>
   </a>
</li>
```

And then modify the JS

JS

```
var positioncontrol = L.control.locate({
   position: 'topleft',
   showCompass: true,
   strings: {title: "Location"},
   icon: 'fas fa-map-marker-alt',
   locateOptions: {enableHighAccuracy: true}
}).addTo(map);

var htmlObject = positioncontrol.getContainer();
var a = document.getElementById('#LocateMe')
function setParent(el, newParent){
  newParent.appendChild(el);
}
setParent(htmlObject, a);
```

Then you have to edit the CSS so it can nicely match with the sidebar

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a onClick on a href

```
<li class="disabled">

    <a href="javascript:LocateMe()" role="tab">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    </a>

</li>
```

EDIT (after you editing the question)

Comment: Ok thanks, any advices on how to call the "CreateButtonCallback" ?